# Расчет времени от одного события до другого. SQL

Tags: sql, clickhouse

```
SELECT moderatorName, status, ts
FROM myDb.myDbEvents
WHERE activity = 'moderator:changed:status'
  AND dayTs = today()
AND moderatorName = 'helper_olesya'
GROUP BY moderatorName, status, ts;
```

Таблица:

```
moderatorName, activity, ts
helper_olesya,offline,2019-09-18 08:16:59
helper_olesya,online,2019-09-18 08:50:46
helper_olesya,online,2019-09-18 07:12:41
helper_olesya,offline,2019-09-18 09:16:37
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посчитать только время от онлайна до офлайна? Буду раз как идеям, направляющим в нужное русло, так запросу.

Comment: Уточните используемую СУБД (нативная, MySQL, что-то ещё?), включая её версию. Доступны ли оконные функции, CTE, пользовательские переменные?

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаком с ClickHouse, но можно попробовать выбрать все `online` события и сделать JOIN с подходящими `offline` событиями. Условия для JOIN что-то вроде `online.ts < offline.ts`.

Будет много совпадений для каждого `online` события, но нам нужно выбрать только то, у которого минимальный `offline.ts`:

```sql
SELECT online.moderatorName,
       online.ts AS online_ts
       MIN(offline.ts) AS offline_ts 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM myDb.myDbEvents 
         WHERE status = 'online' 
         ORDER BY ts ASC
       ) online
  JOIN (SELECT * 
          FROM myDb.myDbEvents 
         WHERE status = 'offline' 
         ORDER BY ts ASC
       ) offline
    ON online.ts < offline.ts
   AND online.moderatorName = offline.moderatorName
 GROUP BY online.moderatorName, online.ts;
```

Запрос на работоспособность не проверял, но идея такая.

Comment: Спасибо за идею, попробую.

Comment: Будут проблемы, к каждому online прилепятся все более поздние offline, если их более одной. Надо выбирать ближайшую... И совсем будет грустно, если имеются пропущенные события. Корректное решение получится значительно сложнее.

Comment: Безусловно это не идеальное решение. Вот если можно изменить схему данных таким образом, чтобы добавить туда какой-нибудь `session_id`, то было бы проще. Тогда данный запрос с модификациями можно использовать чтобы заполнить существующие записи в БД.